# Reconciling three definitions of 'surjective'

Tags: category-theory

[A book](http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/determination-and-choice.html) on Category Theory for programmers defines surjection as such $f: A \to B$ that for any $y: T \to B$ there exists such $x: T \to A$ that $f\circ x = y.$ Then it illustrates it with `all target meals are covered`. I do not see how codomain coverage is related with the definition.

In the end, I see they tell that an arrow 'f' with cancellation property `if t1 ∘ f = t2 ∘ f then t1 = t2` for every 'T' is called an `epimorphism` and it is a generalization of surjectivity.

Can you explain how all these definitions are related? I also do not understand the role of singletone.

Comment: Play with it on paper. What happens when $B$ is a set with two elements?

Comment: This is a bad definition; it's equivalent to the usual definition of a surjection of sets if and only if the axiom of choice holds.

Comment: What would you suggest as the correct definition? As an epi in the category of sets?

Comment: Arrows which are surjective on generalized objects are called "split epimorphisms". In most categories this is much stronger than being surjective. In $\bf{Set} $, the surjective maps are exactly the epimorphisms and AC states that epimorphisms split. In algebraic categories, the correct translation of "surjective" is often "effectively epic", in $\bf {Set} $, this coincides with "epic".

Comment: @JakobWerner Hopefully, somebody will be able to put it `for dummies`.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Take $y=1_B$ to conclude that this definition is equivalent to saying that $f$ is *right invertible*, i.e. is a [split epimorphism](http://nlab.mathforge.org/nlab/show/split+epimorphism).

As the comments say, it is generally a *stronger* property than surjectivity.

Comment: I would like to have more complete answer. I am overloaded with hints. I have also fixed the question: your answer recalled me one more definition from the book. I do not understand why argument was applied to f from the right in the first definition but from the left in the second.